# can a window/tab close be captured using javascript?

Tags: javascript, browser, web, cross-browser

Suppose there is a browser window open with multiple tab, any tab get close then it should be captured using javascript, one thing there is no extension added on browser.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is the [onbeforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onbeforeunload) event you can listen to, which is triggered before the tab or window is closed.

Comment: to mention: this is the one and only way to do that.

Comment: Also, you can only capture this event for the tab/window that the javascript is running in.

Comment: your are right, but if there is any navigation from one page to other page also fire the "onbeforeunload" event.. right? How could it concludes the window/tab close?